# Redirect subdomain to directory

Tags: .htaccess

I want to do this:

sub.domain.com/

**show content of:**

domain.com/test/

I config htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/test/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But It's not working. The url : sub.domain.com still display content of domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute path   insted of using full url

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```